# dollar slash concatination in makefile not working

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I was using the `$\` trick to concatenate lines in a makefile without adding spaces (so for example if I did:)

```
$(info  TEST: 1$\
              2)
```

I would get the expected output

```
TEST: 12
```

without a space between the `1` and the `2`.  I seem to have stumbled upon a corner case that's not acting as I expect however.  If I have the following:

```
$(info TEST: [$(or \
              ,$\
              )])
```

I get the following:

```
TEST: [$]
```

The previous example shows that the `\` has precedence over the `$`, so it *should* resolve to `$(or  ,)`, which should be blank.   Is this a bug in make, or is there an explanation to this behavior?  (I'm using gnu make 4.2.1).

------ EDIT -------

I just verified this does not occur in make 3.81, and thus considering this a bug.  I sent an email to the maintainers.   Leaving this question open in case anyone else runs into the same issue

----- New Edit -----

Ok, update -- it seems that `$(or)` automatically strips all parameters.   This is likely the crux of the problem -- `$(or , $ ,)` would strip each parameter before resolving `$<space>`...   so it would have a second parameter of `$` (no spaces), which resolves to ... `$`.   Sooo... the question now becomes, is this considered correct behavior, or is this a bug?

Comment: Why did you use `\$` in one example and ``$\`` in the other? A typo?

Comment: Is an explicit `$(subst $(newline),,...)` no option? `make` is evil with spaces, and it is especially evil with newlines, now put those two together... no they won't cancel out.

Comment: Yes, typo.   Sorry, fixing.

Comment: @Vroomfondel - I have a bunch of makefiles with 300+ character lines.  I was cleaning them up by putting `\$` after some of the commas to make it more readable, without risking any side effects due to extra spaces.   But then I ran into this.   I am in fact going to have to do something similar to what you suggested...   for this particular case, I'm doing `$(strip $(or cond1,\<newline>, cond2\<newline> ... ))`

Comment: `$(or)` does strip all parameters from (seemingly) superfluous whitespace, *but only in the first parse*.  A `$(info $(or $(space),should not appear))` with a proper definition of the space character will very much print `should not appear`. I suspect this was introduced to save programmers from nearly unintelligible behavour in the logical conditions (when having left a space somewhere) while retaining backwards compatibility regarding parameter evaluation. The result is the usual inconsistency when processing spaces.

Comment: Not very elegant but you could try to break your lines with: `$(\<newline>)`. I admit that starting the next line with a closing parenthesis looks a bit strange...

Comment: Because `$(or ...)` strips its parameters, I can use a simple \, and make will automatically wipe the newly added whitespace (assuming the `\<newline>` is at the beginning/end of a parameter, otherwise I still have to use `\$`...).   Other functions don't strip whitespace though, and so I still have to use `\$` for those..   It's a bit convoluted, but it will at least look nice :-)...

Comment: I am a bit curious about the fact that a single `$` with no following variable name expands to the string literal `$`...   I would have leaned towards making it resolve to nothing, but I'm sure there's reasoning to making it work the way it does.